# Javascript Org Chart with grouping functionality

Tags: javascript, charts, diagram

I'm looking for a Javascript Org Chart library which I can use for a noncommercial educational project. Till now I used the great [draw.io](https://about.draw.io/), but now I have to put it online and the HTML exporter has few options.

There are a lot of great libraries out there, but in the free versions I mostly miss a [grouping functionality](https://balkangraph.com/OrgChartJS/Demos/Grouping), which till know I only found in OrgCharJS (nonfree).

This are my must have features:

- Grouping functionality
- Dynamic alignment when opening+closing groups
- Easy to edit, preferrible by describing the structure by something like JSON or drawing the diagram
- Link nodes/shapes to external web sites